# How to do an if statement in perl?

Tags: perl, perl-module

Having a problem with if statement in Perl, my if statement is not working. What am I doing wrong, because I'm using strict and warnings module, but still my if statement is not working.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;


sub Granted
{
    print "\n\nAccess Granted\n\n";
}


sub Access
{
    print "\n\n\n\n";
    sleep 1;
    print "Enter your name: ";
    my $name = <STDIN>;
    sleep 1;

    if ("$name" eq "jake")
    {
        Granted
    }

}

Access
```

Comment: There's no reason to use `"$name"`. Just use `$name`. But you have to trim the newline at the end of `$name` before you do the comparison.

Comment: Although it's valid like you wrote it (by accident, I guess), please call your subroutines like this: `Granted();`, i.e. with parens `()` and a final `;`. The `;` _may_ be omitted after the last statement in a block (like you do), but it's ugly.

Comment: When in doubt: `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq=1; print Dumper $name;`

Answer (score 2):

You've misdiagnosed the problem. The `if` is fine, the problem is the data you are comparing to the input.

When you read from a file handle, you include the record separator character (by default that is a new line).

You are comparing `"jake\n"` to `"jake"`.

See also `chomp`.